# Using final list with inheritance in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, static, final

I'm new in Java and I was thinking about a particular situation in which we have one superclass and two subclasses. I need to store one static final ArrayList of Strings in each subclass, but due to the fact that they are 2 ArrayList of Strings I was thinking about moving these on the superclass (obviously making one single ArrayList) to avoid duplications and let the subclasses to assign their constant values in the constructor. Can I do something like this? I had some difficulty because the first instruction of subclass constructor must be superclass constructor so I can't declare a local ArrayList in the constructor and then give it to the superclass constructor (so I'm obliged to store this ArrayList in subclass and I'm basically at the start point). What can I do to figure this out?

Comment: Could you post some code with what you've already tried?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do something like this.  The moment you start speaking of `static` any discussion about subclasses and superclasses goes out the window.  Either drop the notion of `static` altogether or abandon all hope of having your subclasses and superclasses share it.  (Hint: dropping `static` is the way to go.)

Edit after clarification by OP: what you need to do is declare an abstract method `getCities()` in your superclass, and then implement this method in each subclass. From this method, each subclass will return its own static list of cities.

Comment: I'll explain better the situation. I must manage two kinds of shipping: a national shipping and an international shipping (they're subclasses of a superclass Shipping). The exercise I'm trying to do tells me to consider a static list of cities for national shipping and a static list of cities for international shipping (and of course the lists are written in the exercise). So I have a further question: if my program basically works just with this lists can I assume in the tester class that I know this cities? I know, it's kind strange and I'm confused too.

Comment: I amended my answer in light of this.

Comment: Another problem: I must pass the start and the destination city to the Spedition constructor when I call it. So I suppose that the method getCities() must be static or I cannot call it